# Do I have to Add All Fields to ModelForm Even If Only One of Them Needs User Input?

Tags: django, django-models, modelform

Only one field needs user input. Others depend on that one field and are programatically populated before saving the form. Adding the other fields to the ModelForm and making them hidden is the only solution or is there a better way?

```
class Sentence(models.Model):
    sent = models.CharField(max_length=150) # Only this field needs user input
    sent_correct = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    msg_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500), blank=True, default=list)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
​
​
class SentenceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sentence
        fields = ['sent']
​
​
# I want to avoid attribute error in the view and programatically populate the fields before saving the form 

def home(request):
    sentences = Sentence.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SentenceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            form.save(commit=False)
            sent = cd['sent']
            # here I need to process sent and populate other fields with 
            # the results then save the form
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'sentences': sentences, 'msg_list': msg_list, 'form': form})
    else:
        form = SentenceForm()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Only put fields in the form if you actually want the user to fill them in

Comment: @DanielRoseman If I put only the required field in the form, will it not raise attribute error if I try to access other fields to populate them before saving the form? The other fields need to be populated programatically before saving the form. I will add view function to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I still don't understand. What would raise an AttributeError and why? If you need to manipulate the object before saving, then capture the results of saving the form with `obj = form.save(commit=False)` then do whatever you want to `obj`. But I don't know where any attribute errors would come from.